# Why the Java runs much faster than c++ in "Remove Duplicates from Sorted List"?

Tags: java, c++, performance

It's a problem from leetcode.Program is easy.But I am confused why Java runs much faster than C++ with same logic?
Java codes:

```
public ListNode deleteDuplicates(ListNode head) {
    if (head == null || head.next == null) return head;

    ListNode runner = head;
    while (runner.next != null) {
        if (runner.val == runner.next.val) { // duplicate values, make the next as next.next
            runner.next = runner.next.next;
        } else { // otherwise, advance runner to runner.next
            runner = runner.next;
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

C++ codes:

```
ListNode* deleteDuplicates(ListNode* head) {
    if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL){
        return head;
    }
    ListNode* index = head;

    while(index->next != NULL){
        if(index->val == index->next->val){
            index->next = index->next->next;
        }else{
            index = index->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Java costs 1ms: https://leetcode.com/discuss/95026/1ms-java-clean-solution

C++ costs 12ms: https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/58563979/

Comment: What is the type of `val`? In Java you just copy a reference to `val` while in C++ you copy the whole object. This could be the key to the runtime difference.

Comment: We have no idea what compiler was used, whether optimizations were used, what the real code actually is (only snippets), no test data, nothing.  We only have a link to something called "leetcode" and their claims.

Comment: And are you sure `runner.val == runner.next.val` really does what you expect in Java? It compares the references, not their values.

Comment: The val just int. Sorry for that I can't get the test cases and complier detail of Leetcode.

Comment: Without seeing the way these benchmarks were derived its hard to ascribe meaning to it. (no, not signing up to leetcode just to see the code)

Comment: The C++ code probably has a memory leak.  Not that I would expect that to explain the performance difference.  The most likely cause is different compilation options, but without knowing what they are or being able to run the code I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't trust a benchmark run for less than a few seconds.

Note: Java's dynamic compiler usually better than C++ at removing dead code i.e. code which isn't used.  I would make sure your test is doing real work and not just being discarded.

In short, Java is often faster for benchmarks which don't do anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

LeetCode seems to measure the execution time of your algorithm differently for each language, as [described on their forums](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/14927/why-are-c-java-so-slow-different-test-cases).